# How transfer to direct_to_template?

Tags: django, django-views

I used this code and it worked.

views.py:

```
from models import Car
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template.context import RequestContext

def custom_proc(request):
    car_list = Car.objects.all()[0:5]
    return {'car_list': car_list}

def article(request, slug):
    text = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('article.html', {'text': text},
     context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors=[custom_proc]))
```

Now, I want to rewrite the views code that they use direct_to_template shortcut.

views.py:

```
from models import Car
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.template.context import RequestContext
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

def custom_proc(request):
    car_list = Car.objects.all()[0:5]
    return {'car_list': car_list}

def article(request, slug):
    text = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
    return direct_to_template(request, 'article.html', {'text': text})
```

Why not work? How I can transfer frequently used objects (from _custom_proc()_) to view(*article()*) and template (*article.html*)?

Also I try:

`return direct_to_template(request, 'article.html', {'text': text}, 'car_list': car_list)`

and this is not work too. Thank you.

Comment: How does it 'not work'? Do you get a template error? An exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two options.

If you want to add a list of cars to *every* template context, add your processor to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) for more info.

If you just want to add it a subset of your templates, use the result of `custom_proc` as you are using `text` in your second example.

Comment: First option it is what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How could either of these work? You're not calling `custom_proc` anywhere. If you want the result of a function in the template, you need to call it and include the result in the context dictionary.

Comment: He uses custom_proc as a context processor, in RequestContext.